# Execute a camel route directly

Tags: java, apache-camel

I recently took over some Java code and there was a method that took in an object and based on some properties of that object, performed some processing on that object.

I was playing around with Apache Camel and was able to define a route that accomplished the same task. Where I am struggling is, how can I find the easiest way to pass an object to the route and execute the logic? What I have right now is a

```
producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:blah", myObject)
```

and the route itself defines a

```
from("direct:blah").process(...)
```

The above is working fine, albeit a little slower than before.

Is this the simplest way to replace the logic of a method? I was hoping to just be able to grab the route itself and pass an object to it for execution, but I don't see any ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a `from().process().` You can also inject an endpoint to your method. For example:

```
@Consume(uri = "direct:blah")
public void onFileSendToQueue(String body, @Header("CamelFileName") String name) {
    LOG.info("Incoming file: {}", name);
    producer.sendBody(body);
}
```

You can do the same for producers as well. See the Camel pojo messaging for more details.
http://camel.apache.org/pojo-messaging-example.html